# Adding curved features to map with ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've tried without much success to add a curved line feature to the ArcGIS JavaScript map.

I created a polygon with a curved edge in ArcMap:
[curved line http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9702/p6mj9B.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9702/p6mj9B.jpg)

However, when I load this same feature in the web API, it becomes segmented:
[segmented curve http://imageshack.com/a/img673/9196/rPnJ4l.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/9196/rPnJ4l.png)

The problem started when I tried to create a curved feature from the JavaScript API itself, which only seems to allow full circle features (not circular arcs).  This makes me think that curves are still unsupported in the JavaScript API.
Do you know any way around this? Do you have any other ideas on alternatives I can use to create and correctly view curved features?

Comment: How do you load it? As a service through ArcGIS for Server?

Comment: @BritishSteel Through a Map service exposed from ArcGIS Server, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArcGIS Server only supports true curves in the response of query requests in 10.3 and only when 'returnTrueCurves' is set to 'true' in the request.  The same functionality is available in hosted feature services in ArcGIS Online as well.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000p1000000

a mechanism to set the appropriate parameter hasn't been ported to the JSAPI yet, but you could use esriRequest.setPreRequestCallback() to intercept and inject it yourself.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html